# How to find/print two consecutive floating point numbers of opposite sign in the same field?

Tags: awk

I am trying to print the occurrences of two consecutive lines (floating point numbers) with opposite sign (+/-). For example, if I have this:

```
 8.00
 89.11
-21.42
-1.98
-44.23
 23.72
 34.21
 56.72
-65.82
-37.49
-23.41
```

I want to print:

```
 89.11
-21.42
-44.23
 23.72
 56.72
-65.82
```

I am wondering what would be the best way to approach it using awk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk 'NR>1&&(p<0&&$0>=0||p>=0&&$0<0){print p;print $0}{p=$0}' file
```

I'm using the variable `p` to store the previous line. Starting from line 2 I'm checking if `(p<0&&$0>=0||p>=0&&$0<0)`

Note: I treat `0` as a positive value in the above solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk '{cV=($0<0)} (NR>1) && (pV!=cV){print p0 ORS $0} {p0=$0; pV=cV}' file
 89.11
-21.42
-44.23
 23.72
 56.72
-65.82
```